# Is there A Standard Format For Describing Network Architecture/Topologies

Tags: networking, diagrams, standards

I'm looking into tools for automatically mapping network resources that create hardware and software diagrams of the network such as WhatsUp Gold, HP TopTools, etc. Is there a standard format, XML schema or otherwise, for describing a network? Something that these autodiscovery tools could import or export? Kind of like a BPMN but for network diagrams instead of business process diagrams.